# Host name duplicate validation

Tags: php, validation, dns

I'm having a form where I allow user to add his host to the database - it can be done either by IP address and domain name.

My problem is - I want to prevent duplicated hosts: when there is one host domain added eg. with address `1.2.3.4` in it's DNS `A` record, user is basically able to change it eg. to `4.3.2.1`, then add another `1.2.3.4` host (by IP) and switch domain `A` record back to `1.2.3.4`.

I could of course verify all host names in my database during submit using `gethostbyname`, but `gethostbyname` does blocking DNS lookup so I'd rather not want to loop it over a large dataset to prevent bad runtime.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: The question isn't super clear, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: @mkaatman The last sentence is what have I tried and ended up with a terrible runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's out of your control**. You can only accept one of both in your database, if you want to ensure that there won't be any duplicates. You could still enable the input of domains, but just resolve them immediately and only save the IP. You can't otherwise be 100% sure that there are no duplicates without checking all of them. If you don't do that, you'll have to relay on old data, which is less accurate. If it's not a big deal that sometimes duplicate entries happen, then it would be the best to detect them one time per day with some script using a cron job or some other tool.

You should first define the minimum of accuracy that your application needs and check later how many resources you have. After that you can calculate how much accuracy you can achieve with your current resources and check then if it's enough. (Assuming you have unused resources, if you have to pay for all used resources, then you should probably just use the minimum you need.)

Some ideas how to optimize your script can be found [here](https://idea.popcount.org/2013-11-28-how-to-resolve-a-million-domains/). I'm also interest in a good and fast solution, I'll maybe write later an optimized script and link it here, but currently I don't have the time.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I needed :)!

Comment: I still don't understand the question entirely, but if you don't want duplicates, could you not simply define the field as unique?

Comment: He is storing domains and IPs, they can only be compared by using DNS records. He is clearly saying that in his question.